# counting a case OR if null

Tags: mysql, if-statement, case

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to integrate my logic here.

There are two scenarios:

1. cn.create_time is null
2. cn.create_time is not null, in which case it contains a timestamp

The start of my select query looks like this:

```
select
    c.eid,
    count(c.eid),
    count(case when c.last_mod < cn.create_time then c.eid end)
```

But what I need is to make the line with the case statement be (in EnSQLish)

```
"if cn.create_time is null then count(c.last_mod), else count(case when c.last_mod < cn.create_time then c.eid end)."
```

Put another way, if create_time is null count all records else only count those records where last_mod is less than create_time.

How would I do that?

Comment: Can you post the structures of the two tables involved here (`c, cn`)? It would help in understanding the join, and how to convert these `COUNT()` probably to `SUM()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
SELECT  c.eid,
        COUNT(c.edi),
        SUM
        (
            CASE
                WHEN cn.create_time IS NULL OR c.last_mod < cn.create_time THEN 1
                ELSE 0
            END
        )
```

Comment: Glad to help! Feel to free mark mine as the answer so other people know that you have had your question answered.

Comment: Done, I tried to initially but SO has a timer that prevented me

Comment: Oh thanks. Good to know. I've never asked a question before so I didn't know that was a thing.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a `SUM()` on indicators instead

select
    c.eid,
    sum(IF(c.last_mod < coalesce(cn.create_time,c.last_mod),0,1)),

If `cn.create_time` is null `coalesce` would return `c.last_mod`

Answer (score 0):

You can make two querys instead of one:

```
select eid, count(eid) FROM Table WHERE create_time IS NULL
select eid, count(eid) FROM Table WHERE NOT create_time IS NULL AND last_mod < create_time
```

Then if you need you can join both.